# Split the subfolders of a repository into their own branches in git

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to make branches from the subfolders in my master branch. Then within each "subfolder" branch I respectively removes the "sibling" subfolders resulting in one branch per subfolder. I'm refactoring an odoo code base where each package/addon resides in the master branch and I would like to have each one on its own branch, that I may or may not merge in later on.

My code is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
master=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
find  . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name "[!.]*" -printf "%f\n" | while read branch
do
   # Use -b if the branches do not exist
   git checkout -b $branch
   # The following can be used to determine which files/folders are removed from the repository
   find ./* -mindepth 1 -path ./.git -prune -o -path ./attooh_sms -prune -o -type f -printf "%p\n" | sed "s|^\./||" > pruned.files
#    cat pruned.files
   # The following removes the specified files and folders from teh repository
   cat pruned.files | while read file
   do
     echo  $file
     git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm '$file'"  -- HEAD
   done
#    git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm $(cat pruned.files | tr '\n' ' ')"  -- HEAD
   git -am "Created the $branch branch from $master removing all other addons"
   git checkout $master
done
```

I keep getting the following error and I can't seem to resolve why this is.

```
fatal: pathspec 'attooh_sms/views/sms_views.xml' did not match any files
```

I believe it is related to bash escaping and I was hoping some one might have a hint for me to follow up on. Essentially I think `"$file"` is collapsing to `""` and this causes the `git rm` call to fail and trips up the `git  filter-branch` as a result. How should I ensure the escaping works properly ?

## Update

For the sake of completeness and for yonder googler I ended up with the following :

```
#!/bin/bash
master=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
find  . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -name "[!.]*" -printf "%f\n" | while read branch
do
   git checkout $branch
   find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -path ./.git -prune -o -path ./$branch -prune -o -type d -printf "%p\n" | sed "s|^\./||" > pruned.files
   git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch $(cat pruned.files|tr '\n' ' ')"  -- HEAD
   echo git checkout $master
done
```

This works alright, the issue was with `git rm` which does not handle directories nor lists of files it seems, but it's not the prettiest and I'm not sure it really achieves what I initially wanted unlike the answer by JTHill

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: I actually want to split the history into branches by folder without using submodules.

Comment: Well then it sounds even more like you want/need to use Submodules

Comment: True, well for the moment I can't the guy I'm working with is still new to git. I figured this might be an easier start for us.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split out branches for each subdirectory of the current tip, this should perform better than the method you've got now:

```
branch=`git symbolic-ref --q --short HEAD` || { echo not on a branch; exit; }
git ls-tree @ | grep ^04 | cut -f2-  \
| while read subdir; do
        git checkout -B $branch-$subdir
        git filter-branch -f --subdirectory-filter $subdir
        git checkout $branch
done
```

That will hoist each subdirectory to the root dir in the new branch, so if you've got a directory `src`, what's still in the `master` history at `src/main.c` will be in the `master-src` history at `main.c`.  If you don't want that, you can drop one level deeper:

```
branch=`git symbolic-ref --q --short HEAD` || { echo not on a branch; exit; }
git ls-tree @ | grep ^04 | cut -f2-  \
| while read subdir; do
        git checkout -B $branch-$subdir
        git filter-branch -f --index-filter '
                git read-tree --empty
                # the `|| git reset etc` here is in case older versions were not dirs
                git read-tree --prefix='$subdir'/ $GIT_COMMIT:'$subdir' ||
                        git reset $GIT_COMMIT '$subdir'
        ' -- HEAD -- $subdir
        git checkout $branch
done
```

Major surgery like this is best done in a scratch repo.

```
git clone -s . `mktemp -d`
cd $_
major surgery here
git push origin master-src
git push origin master-html
etc
cd -
```

so if anything goes wrong you just abandon the clone.

Comment: This works a treat. What is the `$GiT_COMMIT` value though ? I tried echoing it in my shell and got a blank line, one of the branches also errored out saying `fatal:not a valid object name b2d...sd:odoo-example-10 git read-tree --empty git read-tree --prefix=odoo-example-10/@GIT_COMMIT:odoo-example-10`, I thought it might be the number in the branch name but git's happy with that.

Comment: It's a context variable provided by filter-branch for the filters, it's the commit currently being filtered.  btw, I just remembered about ls-tree's `-d` option, you can just `git ls-tree -d @ | while read mode type sha subdir; do etc; done`

Comment: My top suspect for the read-tree error is, that commit deleted the directory in question so filter-branch correctly ran the filter for that commit but I didn't think to write my filter to account for the possibility.  Just adding a ` || true` on the end of the second read-tree will fix the error if that's the problem.

Comment: Okay, just ran it on the full git history, thing that happened was git-gui was originally just a file, read-tree doesn't want to read blobs, it wants to read trees, fixing to allow for the type switch.

Comment: The `|| true` allowed the branch to be created properly, Thanks :D without it it would retain the other folders I intended to drop in the branch. I'll cherry pick against master if anything is missing. I don't quite follow the latest comment though There are some blobby/globby files in the repo that should not be there e.g. `*.jpg` and other image formats, I think there is even a word doc of all things, is this what you mean by blob, or are you referring to the blobs git maintains internally ?

Comment: `blob` is jargon for uninterpreted data, it's how git stores all tracked content. Do `git ls-tree HEAD`, the four types git uses are `blob` and `tree` (close analogs for "file" and "directory" in filesystems) and `tag` (for annotated-tag data) and `commit` (for links to other histories, `git submodule` is the usual helper for wrangling those)

Comment: I knew of `blob`, but I didn't realize that internally there were different types stored. I'll have to go through the docs again. Thanks for the assistance and the additional information :D